# Why does maven download lots of versions of same dependency?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am running a build on maven 3 and its trying to download many different versions of the same JAR. I didn't specify that JAR as a dependency. Any idea why it is doing that?

```
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/maven-metadata.xml (3 KB at 10.8 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 1.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.4.0/jackson-core-asl-1.4.0.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.4.0/jackson-core-asl-1.4.0.pom (1016 B at 5.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.4.1/jackson-core-asl-1.4.1.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.4.1/jackson-core-asl-1.4.1.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.4.2/jackson-core-asl-1.4.2.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.4.2/jackson-core-asl-1.4.2.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.4.3/jackson-core-asl-1.4.3.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.4.3/jackson-core-asl-1.4.3.pom (1016 B at 5.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.4.4/jackson-core-asl-1.4.4.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.4.4/jackson-core-asl-1.4.4.pom (1016 B at 5.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.4.5/jackson-core-asl-1.4.5.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.4.5/jackson-core-asl-1.4.5.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (372 B at 1.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/jackson-core-asl-1.5.0-20100311.071608-6.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/jackson-core-asl-1.5.0-20100311.071608-6.pom (2 KB at 5.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.0/jackson-core-asl-1.5.0.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.0/jackson-core-asl-1.5.0.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.1/jackson-core-asl-1.5.1.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.1/jackson-core-asl-1.5.1.pom (1016 B at 5.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.2/jackson-core-asl-1.5.2.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.2/jackson-core-asl-1.5.2.pom (1016 B at 0.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.3/jackson-core-asl-1.5.3.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.3/jackson-core-asl-1.5.3.pom (1016 B at 5.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.4/jackson-core-asl-1.5.4.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.4/jackson-core-asl-1.5.4.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.5/jackson-core-asl-1.5.5.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.5/jackson-core-asl-1.5.5.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.6/jackson-core-asl-1.5.6.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.6/jackson-core-asl-1.5.6.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.7/jackson-core-asl-1.5.7.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.7/jackson-core-asl-1.5.7.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.8/jackson-core-asl-1.5.8.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.5.8/jackson-core-asl-1.5.8.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (372 B at 1.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/jackson-core-asl-1.6.0-20100831.034125-5.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/jackson-core-asl-1.6.0-20100831.034125-5.pom (2 KB at 5.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.0/jackson-core-asl-1.6.0.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.0/jackson-core-asl-1.6.0.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.1/jackson-core-asl-1.6.1.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.1/jackson-core-asl-1.6.1.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.2/jackson-core-asl-1.6.2.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.2/jackson-core-asl-1.6.2.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.3/jackson-core-asl-1.6.3.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.3/jackson-core-asl-1.6.3.pom (1016 B at 5.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.4/jackson-core-asl-1.6.4.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.4/jackson-core-asl-1.6.4.pom (1016 B at 5.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.5/jackson-core-asl-1.6.5.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.5/jackson-core-asl-1.6.5.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.6/jackson-core-asl-1.6.6.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.6/jackson-core-asl-1.6.6.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.7/jackson-core-asl-1.6.7.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.7/jackson-core-asl-1.6.7.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.0-SNAPSHOT-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.0-SNAPSHOT-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.0-SNAPSHOT-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (381 B at 2.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.0-SNAPSHOT-SNAPSHOT/jackson-core-asl-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT-20101126.221009-1.pom
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.0-SNAPSHOT-SNAPSHOT/jackson-core-asl-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT-20101126.221009-1.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.7.0-SNAPSHOT-20101126.221009-1 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (372 B at 1.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.0-SNAPSHOT/jackson-core-asl-1.7.0-20110105.013252-7.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.0-SNAPSHOT/jackson-core-asl-1.7.0-20110105.013252-7.pom (2 KB at 5.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.0/jackson-core-asl-1.7.0.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.0/jackson-core-asl-1.7.0.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (372 B at 1.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.1-SNAPSHOT/jackson-core-asl-1.7.1-20110111.012521-1.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.1-SNAPSHOT/jackson-core-asl-1.7.1-20110111.012521-1.pom (2 KB at 4.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.1/jackson-core-asl-1.7.1.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.1/jackson-core-asl-1.7.1.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.2/jackson-core-asl-1.7.2.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.2/jackson-core-asl-1.7.2.pom (1016 B at 5.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.3/jackson-core-asl-1.7.3.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.3/jackson-core-asl-1.7.3.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.4/jackson-core-asl-1.7.4.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.4/jackson-core-asl-1.7.4.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.5/jackson-core-asl-1.7.5.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.5/jackson-core-asl-1.7.5.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.6/jackson-core-asl-1.7.6.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.6/jackson-core-asl-1.7.6.pom (1016 B at 5.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.7/jackson-core-asl-1.7.7.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.7/jackson-core-asl-1.7.7.pom (1016 B at 5.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.8.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.8.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.8.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (372 B at 1.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.8.0-SNAPSHOT/jackson-core-asl-1.8.0-20110420.045603-5.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.8.0-SNAPSHOT/jackson-core-asl-1.8.0-20110420.045603-5.pom (2 KB at 5.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.8.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.8.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.8.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (372 B at 1.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.8.1-SNAPSHOT/jackson-core-asl-1.8.1-20110515.143306-1.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.8.1-SNAPSHOT/jackson-core-asl-1.8.1-20110515.143306-1.pom (2 KB at 5.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.8.1/jackson-core-asl-1.8.1.pom
Downloaded: http://CorporateRepo/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.8.1/jackson-core-asl-1.8.1.pom (1016 B at 5.4 KB/sec)
```

Comment: Can we see the dependencies in your pom ?

Comment: It wasn't from my pom but the pom of one of the plugins

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll notice it's not actually downloading the jars, just the POMs.  My **guess** would be that the version being specified is not a fixed version, and that maven is digging through the available versions to figure out which one it should use.

Somewhere in the dependency tree this component is being included.  You can use `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out where.  Of course, it will still need to download all the POMs even in order to show the tree, but you've already got them now :)

Comment: That was it one of the plugins had a bad pom file which was downloading dependencies. Fixed it by excluding that dependency and then explicitly requesting a specific version.